# Selenium, Web Scraping, can't access the class

Tags: class

I am very new to web scraping, It's been several days that I am dealing with the same problem:
Please look at the below line of code(extracted directly from the web page):

< option value='pick' id='ember2314' class='x-option ember view'>To Pick</option

whatever I do I can't access that class:

driver.find_element_by_class_name('x-option ember view') #when I want to print the text here, it says unable to locate element.
But for some other cases, I can easily access the class, and sometimes for some cases, I can't access the class.

Can anyone please shed some light on this? (sorry, I am very new to web scraping)

Please note that the 'id' and 'value' are changing every time so I can't rely on them.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are beginners like me, here is the solution. It is easy to search it with it's xpath:

//tagename[@attribute='value of the attribute']

so for this case:
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//option[@class="x-option ember view"]')

would do the trick.
From my understanding, the 'class' here is actually an attribute of the tag 'option', so search it like this: find_element_by _class_name('x-option ember view') won't give you anything.